# How to get better understanding of error in order to fix

Tags: android, pushy

I'm receiving the following error message in LogCat:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

I'm aware of what a NullPointerException is but not 100% on how to fix this with regards to passing the correct context.  The error only happens when the app is runnning in the background (multitasking) A little guidance would be much appreciated. please Logcat and offending code below. THanks

Logcat:

```
Process: com.app.app, PID: 17519
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:537)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:526)
    at com.app.app.DatabaseHandling.UpdateData.<init>(UpdateData.java:70)
    at com.app.app.PushService.PushReceiver$1.run(PushReceiver.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

PushReceiver

```
UpdateData updateData = new UpdateData(MainActivity.mainActivity);
```

UpdateData:

```
 private final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.mainActivity);
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is, that you try to initialise the **SharedPreferences sp** at the location, where you define it.
You should define it first like:

```
private SharedPreferences sp;
```

After that, set this global variable **sp** in a function like "onReceive(Context context)":

```
sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Or like already mentioned in the Activity itself in the function "onCreate(...)":

```
sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
```

The problem might be, that you try to initialize a variable with a context (like activity), that is not available at this point, but in a later step of the lifecycle.

And avoid to hand over a context supplied by a static variable from another class.

Comment: Well explained, really helped me to understand thank you.

Answer (score 1):

most likely (based upon the limited example provided, which does not even indicate, within which context that code runs), it should rather be:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
```

because one cannot just make up static fields, which do not exist -

while assigning `Context` classes (alike `Activity` or `Context`) to `static` fields is generally bad practice... and should be avoided, whenever just possible.

Comment: I had previously attempted that, however, it displayed the error 'MainActivity is not an enclosing class'

Comment: @astricmobiles if this code does not run within the `MainActivity`, that error message should be the result. `getApplicationContext()` may provide the `Context`, independent of an `Activity`.

Comment: the variable definition is made with "private" so it is a global variable. It could also be a lifecycle problem, that might not be always solvable by using "MainActivity.this".

Comment: @ThomasRichter as the question is written, this could have various reasons (it completely lacks the structural context - just alike the code lacks the `Context`).

Comment: exactly, it lacks for various reasons

Answer (score 0):

First you shuld check your code. you are passing **MainActivity.mainAcitvity** instead of **MainACtivity.this** or **getApplicationContext()**

```
private final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.mainActivity);
```

always pass context of activity in which your method works ...